# Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for free storage for projects

Tags: google-bigquery, quota

I am using BigQuery Sandbox (Free Plan) and integration with Google Analytics. Two week ago I got error "Quota exceeded". I removed all tables but It doesn't help - Load job details still show "Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for free storage for projects."

Should I wait 1 month and quota will be refreshed? Or the only one solution - set up billing and use paid plan? I want to keep the Free plan.

Comment: Yeah bigquery pricing storage is usage over time -- meaning you've already used space for a certain amount of time, even if you delete it now, you had been storing it.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Then, what does mean this sandbox limits PER MONTH: You are granted the same free usage limits as BigQuery's free tier: 10 GB of active storage and 1 TB of processed query data per month. I got it here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-cloud-console?hl=id#expandable-1

Comment: As you say the sandbox limits what you can do for a month, if you want more storage you will need to set up a billing method so you can increase it, but if you want a more manageable storage for your sandbox you can follow this best practices https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-storage

Comment: It's not for a month for sandbox, documentation is wrong, I don't get 1GB of free storage for new month. I removed all tables month ago. I got it, the only one help from you is set up billing

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution?

Comment: I set up billing